# How to find the mean of a list with mixed symbols (numbers and characters) in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Given a list of the type '('a 1 'b 2 'c 3) I want to calculate the mean of the numbers in the list.

This is what I have done so far: I have written 3 functions that work correctly, one to remove the characters, the other to calculate the sum of the numbers in a list, and the other to find the average. But I do not know how to put them together to solve my problem.

```
;remove all non numbers from a list:
(define (all-numbers x)
  (cond ((null? x) null)
        ((integer? (car x)) (cons (car x) (all-numbers (cdr x))))
        (else (all-numbers (cdr x)))))

;sum the elements of the list
(define (sumlist lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        (( + (car lst) (sumlist (cdr lst))))))

; find the mean of the list
(define (a_mean lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
    ((/ (sumlist lst) (length lst)))))

(a_mean '(1 2 3))

;find the mean of a mixed list
(define (m_mean lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
    ((/ (sumlist ((all-numbers lst)) (length (all-numbers lst)))))))

(m_mean '('a 1 'b 2 'c 3))
```

I get an error in the above code for m_mean. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Óscar López should fix your problems.

I will now provide a more concise way of solving the same problem:

```
(define (m-mean lst)
  (define all-numbers (filter number? lst))  ; Filter out all the non-numbers.
  (if (null? all-numbers)
    0  ; The mean is 0 if there are no numbers.
    (/ (apply + all-numbers) (length all-numbers))))  ; Calculate mean.
```

This way, you do not have to explicitly define the `all-numbers` and `sumlist` functions.

Comment: Bravo! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For starters, some of your `cond` expressions are missing the `else` keyword in the final condition - this is mandatory, as you did in `all-numbers`. Also, in `m_mean` there are a couple of incorrect brackets; this should fix the errors:

```
(define (m_mean lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        (else (/ (sumlist (all-numbers lst))
                 (length (all-numbers lst))))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(m_mean '(a 1 b 2 c 3))
=> 2
```